# Proper way for two-way sorting

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I've got a simple java pojo which looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
  public String getGroup();
  public String getTitle();
}
```

Now what I want to do is to primarily sort a list of MyClass pojo by the values returned by the getTitle() method. Easy going though using my own comparator. However, what I want is that instances with the same value returned by getGroup() being followed by each other. Now what I did was something like

```
.. compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2)
{
  if (c1.getGroup().compareTo(c2.getGroup()) == 0)
  {
    return c1.getTitle().compareTo(c2.getTitle());
  }
  return c1.getGroup().compareTo(c2.getGroup());
}
```

However, the issue of this code is that it is no longer primarily sorted by the title because I do first compare the content of the groups, not the title, so a group starting with "B" would come before a group starting with "C" eventhough its title may come first.. what's the proper way to primarily sort by title but make sure groups are "groupped" together as well?

Sample data:

```
MyClass 1 (group = "A", title="5")
MyClass 2 (group = "B", title="9")
MyClass 3 (group = "B", title="1")
```

Using my previous code would end up in

```
MyClass 1 (group = "A", title="5")
MyClass 3 (group = "B", title="1")
MyClass 2 (group = "B", title="9")
```

-> sort by group, then sort by title

But I want

```
MyClass 3 (group = "B", title="1")
MyClass 2 (group = "B", title="9")
MyClass 1 (group = "A", title="5")
```

-> sort by title but make sure each equal group follows each other that's why still MyClass 1 with title "5" comes after MyClass 2 with title "9"...

Comment: It's not clear what you want. It's got to be *either* primarily sorted by title *or* primarily sorted by group. Please give some sample data and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Is there any logical relation between a `group` and a `title`?

Comment: Nope there's not. Title is for sorting, group is for keeping thing in order (after title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done with a Comparator. You need to run through the sorted titles, then for each unvisited title sort the corresponding groups. Here's some sample code that sorts like the way you wanted.

```
public class MyClass {
    private String  group;
    private String  title;

    public MyClass(String g, String t) {
        group=g;
        title=t;
    }

    static Comparator<MyClass>  TITLE_COMPARATOR    = 
            new Comparator<MyClass>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
                            return c1.title.compareTo(c2.title);
                    }
            };
    static Comparator<MyClass>  GROUP_COMPARATOR    = new Comparator<MyClass>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
                            return c1.group.compareTo(c2.group);
                    }
            };

    public static List<MyClass> sublist(List<MyClass> list, String group) {
            ArrayList<MyClass> ret = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
            for (MyClass mc : list)
                if (mc.group.equals(group))
                    ret.add(mc);
            return ret;
        }

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    ArrayList<MyClass> sorted = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

    ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    list.add(new MyClass("A", "5"));
    list.add(new MyClass("B", "9"));
    list.add(new MyClass("B", "1"));
    Collections.sort(list, TITLE_COMPARATOR);
    Hashtable<String, Boolean> visited = new Hashtable<String, Boolean>();
    for (MyClass mc : list) {
        if (visited.get(mc.group) == null) {
            List<MyClass> sublist = sublist(list, mc.group);
            Collections.sort(sublist, GROUP_COMPARATOR);
            sorted.addAll(sublist);
            visited.put(mc.group, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }

    for (MyClass mc : sorted)
        System.out.println(mc.group + " " + mc.title);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> what's the proper way to primarily sort by title but make sure groups are "groupped" together as well?

To sort by title and *then* by group, just switch `getGroup()` and `getTitle()` everywhere in your comparator.

Here is an alternative, simplified, version:

```
int compare(MyClass c1, MyClass c2)
{
  int cmp = c1.getTitle().compareTo(c2.getTitle());
  if (cmp == 0) {
    cmp = c1.getGroup().compareTo(c2.getGroup());
  }
  return cmp;
}
```

If that's not what you are trying to achieve, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants either

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense: Being "grouped together" means sorting by *group* first, then by *title*.

There's just no getting around it.

I think you really want what you already coded.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .getGroup instead of .getTitle (and vice-versa) in your Comparator. I think you just should do what you're doing the other way around.