# Painting boxes in iText PDF

Tags: java, itext

I know that **iText** PDF supports painting paragraphs which is quite good. However, I was wondering whether (besides using tables) is it possible to do custom drawing of the background of paragraphs, like adding a rounded border box etc.?
I know that there's the *VerticalPositionMark* interface that allows one to paint on the current y position, however for a paragraph I'd need to know his exact positions to be able to paint into the background first (including any margin from the paragraph etc.).
Is there any way besides using tables for every single box?

thanks!
Alex

Comment: How am I supposed to do that when most of my questions didn't receive an usable answer or something that could be accepted because it was simply not right?!

Comment: Right, I understand. My first action is to answer your sorting problem, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064432/proper-way-for-two-way-sorting/11972045#11972045